# Testing whether a string is made up of all lower-case letters, without repeated letters

Tags: python, string, python-2.7

I am trying to figure out why the following code doesn't work.
The code seems correct to me but it always returns True.

```
import string
lower_alpha = string.ascii_lowercase
def no_repeat_loweralpha_1 (string):
    for i in range(len(string)):
        if not string[i] in lower_alpha: return False
        if string[i] in string[:i]: return False
        else: return True
string = 'ab/!34cda56aaa1..,efgahijk'
print no_repeat_loweralpha_1(string)
# OUTPUT: True
```

Here is another variant of the code which has the same problem:

```
def no_repeat_loweralpha_2(string):
    for i in range(len(string)):
        if string[i] < 'a' or string[i] > 'z' : return False
        if string[i] in string[:i]: return False
        else: return True
string = 'ab/!34cda56aaa1..,efgahijk'
print no_repeat_loweralpha_2 (string)
# OUTPUT: True
```

**Edit:**

Is there a shorter way to write a function that achieves this? How can I write the function using lambda?

Comment: reduce the indent for `else: return True`

Comment: Thank you, that fixed it. Could you please explain it?

Comment: You're returning true after checking the first character.

Comment: You named your variable `string` and you are also importing the library `string`. This will lead to problems later. Avoid using variables that are the same as built-ins.

Comment: Thank you for the tip, I will use s, sentence, text, etc. next time.

Answer (score 1):

A more pythonic version would have been something like this:

```
return s.isalpha() and s.islower() and len(s) == len(set(s))
```

Comment: Does this also check whether s is all alpha?

Comment: Thank you. I like the use of set, I didn't think of that.

Comment: You don't need to check if its alpha because only letters can be lowercase anything else will return false for `.islower()`.

Comment: @BurhanKhalid no that's not correct.  `'google.com'.islower()` is True for example

Comment: Yes in your case it doesn't matter - it only applies if you are stepping and checking each character, because '.'.islower() is False

Answer (score 0):

Here's another approach. Collect all unique lowercase letters, and check the length against your original:

```
def no_repeat_lower_alpha(foo):
   s = set()
   for i in foo:
      if i.islower():
          s.add(i)
   return len(s) == len(foo)
```

Answer (score 0):

try the following code

```
def lower_and_duplicate(str_test):
    dict_found_chars = {}
    for char in str_test:

        if not char.islower():
            return False

        if dict_found_chars.has_key(char):
            return False
        else:
            dict_found_chars[char] = 1

    return True

print lower_and_duplicate("aAsdfsdfsdf")
print lower_and_duplicate("aasdfsdfsdf")
print lower_and_duplicate("abcdefgh")
```

The dict checks for duplicates and we test for lowercase at each step

Answer (score -1):

Shorter version:

```
all(x in lower_alpha  and s.count(x) < 2 for x in s)
```

If any char is not lowercase or the count is > 1 it will return False

You could remove the string import with:

```
all( x.isalpha() and x.islower() and s.count(x) < 2 for x in s)
```

Comment: It is not efficient to call `.count` multiple times in a loop

Comment: @wim, the OP asked for a shorter way to write the function which I have provided

Comment: I see that, I'm just pointing out that this is an O(n^2) solution when an easy O(n) solution also exists

Comment: @wim on a small string I did not see a big difference and on certain strings this will actually be faster than your set solution